# Disable editing of Recipients and message body in MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am integrating a MFMessageViewController and I want to disable the editing area of Recipients and message body in MFMessageComposeViewController.I know this is an old question and I have read in the documents that we cannot customise the UI of the MFMessageController. I found some private APIS that related to chatkit framework and What we are doing here is in our MFMessageComposeViewController I'm getting a object of private CKSMSComposeController.So right now what I am doing is just for exploring the private api's but still not working.
I have gone through the below links and and other documents but no luck. Any help appreciated.

*1.https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/ChatKit.framework/CKSMSComposeController.h.

2. [How to access the method in the Private API framework and pass the value to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68208058/how-to-access-the-method-in-the-private-api-framework-and-pass-the-value-to-it).

3.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68224265/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-disable-adding-editing-of-the-recipients*